# Remove default quicktags

Tags: quicktag

I only want to display a subset of the buttons on the html editor button bar. What is the proper way to remove some of the quicktags? For intance I don't want it to offer "proofread".

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using the [**`quicktag_settings`**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/quicktags_settings/) filter

```
function wpse41427_remove_quicktags( $qtInit ) {
    $qtInit['buttons'] = 'strong,em,link,block,del,img,ul,ol,li,code,more,spell,close,fullscreen';
    return $qtInit;
}
add_filter('quicktags_settings', 'wpse41427_remove_quicktags');
```

The default buttons for quicktags is a comma seperated value for the buttons key:

```
$qtInit['buttons'] = 'strong,em,link,block,del,img,ul,ol,li,code,more,spell,close,fullscreen';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [TinyMCE Advanced Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tinymce-advanced/) that let you configure the Wordpress editor, removing the undesidered buttons.

Install it, via Plugins -> Add New

EDIT:
For HTML Editor, try to use the [HTML Editor Reloaded](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/html-editor-reloaded/) plugin.

Comment: Using the HTML editor not TinyMCE. I think quicktags are only for the HTML editor.

Comment: I've updated the answer with the HTML Editor Reloaded

Comment: I've already got it, but it only seems to provide for adding shortcodes, like other utilities of its type. I know it can be done because some of the default buttons have functions other than adding shortcodes. I'm trying to avoid having to reverse engineer those.